# AspNetCore Identity Configuration

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

i'm trying to configure an aspnetcore mvc project to use AspNetCore.Identity but have problems signingin the user.
The PasswordSignInAsync method returns Succeded but it keeps redirecting me to the login page.

that's how the app is configured

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<HandlerContext, HandlerSqlLiteContext>(x => 
x.UseSqlite("Data Source=TestDB.db;"));
builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(x => 
x.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<HandlerSqlLiteContext>();
            
builder.Services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(opt =>
{
   opt.Password.RequireDigit = true;
   opt.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
   opt.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
   opt.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;
   opt.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
});

builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddNegotiate();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
  options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
  app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
  app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(name: "default",pattern: " 
 {controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

and that's the action code

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string ReturnUrl)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync("a@b.c");
            if (user == null)
                return View();
            var password = await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, "test1234!");
            if (password)
            {
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync("test", "test1234!", true, false);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    var userPrincipal = await _signInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(user);
                    var identity = userPrincipal.Identity;
                    return Redirect(ReturnUrl);
                }
            }
            return View();
        }
```

Any Help?
Thanks